# Why is there an indentation error here and how to fix it?

Tags: python, indentation

Hi I barely know anything about python and just copied some code for my school project and it shows an indentation error even though im pretty sure it's indented properly.

```
    from scipy.integrate import odeint
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# DEFINE CONSTANTS
β = 1
δ = 1/5
N = 100000
γ = 1/10
α = 5/100
ρ = 1/15

# FUNCTION TO RETURN DERIVATIVES AT T
def f(y,t):
    S, E, I, R, D = y # get previous values of S, E, I, R, D and store them in array y
    d0 = -β*(S/N)*I # derivative of S(t)
    d1 = β*(S/N)*I - δ*E # derivative of E(t)
    d2 = δ*E - (1-α)*γ*I - α*ρ*I # derivative of I(t)
  d3
```

When i copy paste the code here it shows d3 as being unindented but in replit it looks like it is indented properly

I tried pressing space and delete to move d3 around but it still showed an indentation error

[here it looks like its indented](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InM5f.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include all code and errors as text and not as an image.

Comment: The fact there is a difference between how the code shows here and how the code shows on your IDE indicates a tab/space issue. Double check if the leading character is a tab or a space.

Comment: check for which line you are getiing this error

Comment: @blackbrandt so do i have press tab instead of space or something?

Comment: Source view shows you've got mixed tabs and spaces. That's the problem. Stick to spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running your code, you had an error with line 1 & line 19.
Line one error is due to the fact that you had 4 spaces (for no apparent reason).
Line 19 is due to the fact that you were missing 2 spaces & you haven't defined the variable d3.

Here's the updated code:

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# DEFINE CONSTANTS
β = 1
δ = 1/5
N = 100000
γ = 1/10
α = 5/100
ρ = 1/15

# FUNCTION TO RETURN DERIVATIVES AT T
def f(y,t):
    S, E, I, R, D = y # get previous values of S, E, I, R, D and store them in array y
    d0 = -β*(S/N)*I # derivative of S(t)
    d1 = β*(S/N)*I - δ*E # derivative of E(t)
    d2 = δ*E - (1-α)*γ*I - α*ρ*I # derivative of I(t)
    d3 #<- needs to be defined
```

Comment: My pleasure! Feel free to upvote for those sweet reputation points :)

Comment: i unfortunately dont have enough rep to upvote this

Comment: No worries. I'm glad your issue is resolved :)